# “Objects are not valid as a React child”

Tags: javascript

```
    import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react"
    import axios from "axios"
    import './App.css';
    import Move from "./Move";
    
    
    function App() {
      const [data,setData] = useState([]);
      useEffect(()=> {
       axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key={apikey}&language=en-US&page=1").then((res)=> {
        setData(res.data.results)
       
       
       })
      },[])
    
      return (
       <div>
        
        <div className="App">
    <input placeholder="enter something" />
    <label></label>
        </div>
        {
        data.map(function(movie){
          console.log(movie)
        const title = movie.title
        const id = movie.id
         
        return <Move key={id} title={title}  />
    })}
        </div>
      );
    
    
    
    
      }
    
    
    
    
    
    export default App;
Component Im Trying To Render
import React from 'react'

const Move = (title) => {
  return (
      <div>
    <div>Move</div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>

</div>
  )
}

export default Move
```

im trying get access properties of the object for example title but im getting the error “Objects are not valid as a React child”

the object is :

```
{
    "adult": false,
    "backdrop_path": "/iQFcwSGbZXMkeyKrxbPnwnRo5fl.jpg",
    "genre_ids": [
        28,
        12,
        878
    ],
    "id": 634649,
    "original_language": "en",
    "original_title": "Spider-Man: No Way Home",
    "overview": "Peter Parker is unmasked and no longer able to separate his normal life from the high-stakes of being a super-hero. When he asks for help from Doctor Strange the stakes become even more dangerous, forcing him to discover what it truly means to be Spider-Man.",
    "popularity": 8450.164,
    "poster_path": "/1g0dhYtq4irTY1GPXvft6k4YLjm.jpg",
    "release_date": "2021-12-15",
    "title": "Spider-Man: No Way Home",
    "video": false,
    "vote_average": 8.4,
    "vote_count": 8021
}
```

not sure what the problem is

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the `.map` statement and closing divs you provided. You may need to show us more of the component.

Comment: i added all the code

Comment: What results do you get when you ```console.log(data);```  You might be looping over a wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const Move = (title) => {
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <div>Move</div>
>       <h1>{title}</h1>
>     </div>
>   );
> };
> ```

In this code, `title` is the entire props object. You need to access just the title property on that object:

```
const Move = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Move</div>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or with destructuring:

```
const Move = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Move</div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'

const Move = (prop) => {
  return (
      <div>
    <div>Move</div>
    <h1>{prop.title}</h1>

</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You should better explain why you propose this answer. looks to the other answer for a good example of what is a valuable answer on stackoverfow